# Kind Assistance with Displaying Login Errors on Home Page

Tags: php, html, mysqli, authentication

I am testing the login system for a study planner that I am building. As for now, the application seems to let me log in and logout okay but the current problem I have is that it won’t display an error messages (`$error` variable) on the index.php (which were initialised in the login.php file) when it is supposed to. So, I am wondering if someone could please point me in the right direction, as I cannot seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

I could post the whole files but apart from the fact that I don’t want to inundate a potential helper, I have included the files which I believe the most important, that is, the login.php and index.php but I can include the others too if need be.

Thanking you in advance.

Login.php:

```
<?php

// Start session
session_start();
// Variable to store error message
$error = '';
// If the login form (Note that the 'submit' refers to the 'name' attribute of the login form) has been submitted...
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // If username or password is not provided...
    if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
        // ...tell user that login details are invalid.
        $error = "Please fill in both your username and your password";
        // Else...
    } else {
        // ...put the provided username and password in variables $username and $password, respectively
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        // Establish connection to the server
        $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
        // set up measures to counter potential MySQL injections
        $username = stripslashes($username);
        $password = stripslashes($password);
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $username);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $password);
        // Select Database
        $db = mysqli_select_db($mysqli, "p00702");
        // SQL query to fetch information of registerd users and find user match.
        $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * from logins WHERE password='$password' AND username='$username'");
        // Return the number of rows of the query result and put it in $rows variable
        $rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
        // If rows are equal to one...
        if ($rows == 1) {
            // Initialize session with the username of the user...
            $_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;
            // ...and redirect to the homepage.
            header("Location: welcome.php");
            // Make sure that codes below do not execut upon redirection.
            exit;
        // Else, 
        } else {
            // redirect user to the home page (index.php)
            header("Location: index.php");
            // and tell user that the login credentials are invalid.
            $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
        }
        // ...and close connection
        mysqli_close($mysqli);
    }
}
```

Index.php:

```
<?php
include ('login.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/images/favicon.png"/>
        <title>Just-Read</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Link to external JavaScript file -->
        <script src="javascript/validator.js"></script>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="header">
                <!-- Web site Logo -->
                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="images/logo.png" width="128" height="93.5" alt="Logo" class="logo"/>
                </div>
                <div id="logoText">
                    <h1>Just Read</h1>
                </div>
                <div id="registerLink">
                    <!-- Registration link -->
                    <h5>New around here? <a href="registration.php">Register</a></h5>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="leftColumn">
                <h4>Your study companion</h4>
            </div>
            <div id="rightColumn">
                <!-- Authentication Form -->
                <form name="authentication" action="login.php"  autocomplete="on" method="POST">
                    <div class="login">
                        <label><b>Username*</b></label>
                        <input type="email" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Enter your email" autofocus value=""/>
                        <label><b>Password*</b></label>
                        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password" value=""/>
                        <button name="submit" type="submit">Log in</button>
                        <div id="mandatoryFields">
                            <h4>* Mandatory Fields</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <span>
                        <?php
                        echo $error;
                        ?>
                    </span>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="footer">
                <div id="footerText">
                    Copyright &copy; 2017, Chizzy Meka.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try `var_dump($error)` it may be empty

Comment: @FastSnail Oh yeah! I think it is empty, after all. I am new to PHP so I don’t quite know what’s going on for sure but it now says: C:\wamp64\www\justread\index.php:48:string '' (length=0). Which could suggest it is empty. Any ideas on how could rectify it, please?

Comment: in some conditions you don't assign a error.for example if `($rows == 1) {`

Comment: have you tried by removing this line `header("Location: index.php");` before `$error` variable?

Comment: @FastSnail I will try that now and let you know. Thank you.

Comment: @MaheshSinghChouhan Yes, I tried removing it but the application no longer returns to the index.php. the URL remains stuck on login.php, with nothing but a white page showing. Thank you.

Comment: @ChizzyMeka since you are redirecting error variable will not work as you think.you should post error variable when you redirect to login page again(when password incorrect)

Comment: @FastSnail First, thank you for taking the time to reply to me. I have tried all suggestions but it won’t work. However, I am wondering if it would make things easier if I included the login script on the index.php file. Please advise me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

You can send `error` in url in `edit.php` and catch error on `index.php` like below:

**Edit.php**

```
header("Location: index.php?error=" . $error);
```

**Index.php**

```
<?php echo isset($_GET['error']) ? $_GET['error'] : ""; ?>
```

**Solution 2:**

You can store error in session varialbe in edit.php and catch error on index.php like below:

**Edit.php**

```
$error = "Username or Password is invalid";
$_SESSION['error'] = $error;
// redirect user to the home page (index.php)
header("Location: index.php");
```

**Index.php**

```
<?php echo isset($_SESSION['error']) ? $_SESSION['error'] : ""; ?>
```

Make sure to unset `$_SESSION['error']` if `$rows == 1`

```
if ($rows == 1) {
    unset($_SESSION['error']);
```

Comment: First, thank you for taking the time to reply to me. I have tried all suggestions but it won’t work. However, I am wondering if it would make things easier if I included the login script on the index.php file. Please advise me.

Comment: Thank you very much. This particular error ("Username or Password is invalid") is now printing but not the other one ("Please fill in both your username and your password"), so I am wondering  if you think I should use another variable, for example error2 for the other error?

$error2 = "Username or Password is invalid";
            $_SESSION['error2'] = $error2;

And print it on the index. Page like: <?php echo isset($_SESSION['error2']) ? $_SESSION['error2'] : ""; ?>

Comment: Yes you can use the same example for other errors, but if you want to show error on same place then you can overwrite with same variable

Comment: Thank you again. May you also find help when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

You could initialize an **empty** `array` for errors and grab all your `errors` in it and then **loop** through that `array` and `echo` them for example:

```
$errors = [];
if(empty username or password) {
  $errors[] = 'username or email could not be empty';
}
if(username or password) {
 $errors[] = 'Username or Password is invalid';
}
// add all your conditions and get all errors
```

then you can check if you have errors in your errors array

```
if(count($errors)) {
  $errors_ul = '<ul>';
  foreach($errors as $error) {
    $errors_ul .= '<li>'.$error.'</li>'; 
  }

  $errors_ul .= '</ul>';

  echo $errors_ul;

} else {
  // log the user in
}
```

Comment: First, thank you for taking the time to reply to me. I have tried all suggestions but it won’t work. However, I am wondering if it would make things easier if I included the login script on the index.php file. Please advise me.